# How to speed up SQL table response time and set proper Indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table, like you can see below

```
Listings
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ListingID            Make       Model     Year          Zipcode 

1                    BMW        325       2009          90210
2                    Mercedes   330 C     2006          33160
3
```

about 2 millions rows. Each day I'm adding new rows and deleting old ones.

Within my application I query this table, by listingid, by make, by make and model, by make model and zipcode.

I have clustered index on ListingID, and non-clustered on all others columns.

if I query table by listingid, I get very fast response. by make, model, zipcode it's very slow. for example to return 10000 records with joining table with zipcodes, about 25-30 secs.

here is the size of this table

[image]

Here is the example of query I use to return listing within specific radius.

1. First based on zipcode and radius, with help of function I insert zipcode into temp table #CloseZips (takes 0 sec). This procedure returns zipcode within radius very fast 0 sec.
2. Second I join with listings table, you can see. This part takes time 25-60 secs

   ```
           SELECT ListingID, Make, Model, Year, L.Zipcode, Year
       FROM Listings L WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN  #CloseZips Z ON Z.ZipCode = L.Zipcode 
       WHERE L.Make = @Make AND L.Model = @Model AND L.IsActive = 1
       ORDER BY Z.Distance DESC
   ```

**Questions:**

1. What woulb be the right approach to impove performance on that kind
   of size tables?
2. Do I need to have indexes on all columns?
3. What is the best way to maintain tables like this?

Comment: what do you mean by "with joining table with zipcodes" ?

Comment: when I search by radius, I join two tables zipcodes and listings to return listings within radius

Comment: what indexes does zipcodes have ? and how does the slow query look like ?

Comment: As you query by make, or make+model, or make+model+zipcode, a **single** non-clustered index on `(make, model, zipcode)` should do. It can be used to satisfy all three of your query types. Since you're also joining to a separate table on `ZipCode` you might also want to put a separate nonclustered index on that single column as well

Comment: I have non-clustered indexes on zipcodes table (zipcode column) and also on listings table non-clustered indexes on make, model, zipcode columns

Comment: Yes, that's what you said - and I'm telling you: for this, you only need **one SINGLE index** on `(make, model, zipcode)` - this single index can be used for queries on just the make, on make+model, and for queries on make, model, zipcode. Benefit is: only one single index to keep updated!

Comment: MasterMeNow: a **SINGLE COMPOSITE index** on...

Comment: I made it as Single Composite index. It takes the same time to execute query. For example localy it takes 1 sec to return 24K records in production 25 secs

Comment: what is `Z.Distance` ? and what happens if you ommit the `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: IN that case - you need to start looking at the query execution plan and find out where the problem lies...

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to help you optimize a query when you didn't give the actual query itself, but here it goes:

- If you're joining the table zipcodes, make sure that the zip code column is indexed in that table.
- There's part of the query that you haven't discussed, which is how you evaluate the nearness of one zip code to another.  Your query will have to solve that part of the problem also, and I'm guessing that part is written in such a way that it's not indexed.
- If you have separate indexes on make, model, and zipcode, and you search on all three columns only one index will be used.  You'll need to use the EXPLAIN tool to discover which one it is — it may not be the optimal one.
- Since, according to your description, a search **always** involves a make, and the searches that include zipcode always involve the model too, I would replace your indexes on make and model with a single index on (make, model, zipcode).  This can be used against any of your queries to provide an indexed search.  (You will probably still need the zipcode index for the JOIN).

Again, post the complete SQL query and we may be able to be of more assistance.

Comment: I updated my questions. Please let me know if you need additional information

Comment: Are you remembering to create an index on #CloseZips(zipcode)?  And how many rows are in that table?

Comment: Okay so #CloseZips it's a temp table. I insert into zipcodes within radius. As I said before it takes 0 sec.

Comment: Yes, but are you creating an index on that temp table?  Since that's the one you're joining back to the main listing table, it's there that you need the index.  If you create it and don't explicitly index it, it will slow down that JOIN.  (Create the index after populating the table for speed).